# eclipse android turn off ndk auto build

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, auto-build

In Eclipse, every time I select run->Android application, a full build is performed including the NDK. This is time consuming and wasteful when I am working on the Java code. Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to:

```
Project Properties -> Builders
```

the `CDT builder` checkbox is the native builder. uncheck the checkbox

Comment: Thanks for your response. This disables the NDK Build. How do I then perform an NDK-Build using Eclipse? Is there any way manually build the native component and auto build the java component?

Comment: simply re-enable the checkbox when you need to perform native build

Comment: Thanks again. Thats a good workaround, also I can execute ndk-build from a cmd prompt. Thought there would be a better way to achieve this though.

Answer (score 3):

check `Project - Build Automatically`. it's probably checked. Trun it of and you have to manually do a Clean/Build